# Site-To-Site Data synchronization Over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, synchronization, data-warehouse, web-services

I'm developping a distributed solution with a WebSite and a Corporate Application Management.

Here is the architecture :

> **Web Site :**
>
> - Database (SQL Server)
> - Web Site : ASP.NET MVC
> - Data synchronization Services (WCF)

-

> **Corporate Management Application :**
>
> - Database (SQL Server)
> - WinForm Application
> - Data synchronization Services (WCF)

I want to perform Site-To-Site data synchronization.

**Note** : The Corporate Management Application Database is the Warehouse datastore.

Usually i want Corporate side asks Web Site for data synchronization.

So here is the scenario :

- (WebSite Side) Some data changed => Local DataStore
- (Corporate Side) Ask WebSite for changes => Sync data from Web Site datastore to warehouse datastore
- (Corporate Side) Some data changed => Warehouse store => Sync to WebSite Local Datastore

How can i achieve this and what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the Microsoft Sync Framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx

I've used it successfully over a WCF channel to synchronize the state of 2 databases. The Sync Framework site is pretty good at working though your requirements and showing you how to approach the problem. If you can get away with using the change tracking built into SQL Server, it should fall together pretty quickly.